# Why is the Capacitor Inductance Positive in Transfer Function?

Tags: capacitor, transfer-function

When solving AC circuits capacitive impedance is always negative. But when finding a transfer function (either the input voltage or input voltage) the capacitive impedance is left positive like in the circuit shown. Why?

[image]

Comment: Finding the transfer function of what circuit in particular?

Comment: You realize that \$1/j = -j\$, right?

Comment: You're probably confusing the \$j\omega\$ notation with the Laplace \$s\$. As @ThePhoton says, for impedance you'd use \$1/j\omega=-j/\omega\$, but for transfer function you use \$1/sC\$, thus \$R/(R+1/sC)=sRC/(1+sRC)\$, or first order highpass.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function of that circuit is

$$\tilde{v}_o = \frac{R}{R+1/j\omega{}C}\tilde{v}_i$$

The impedance of the capacitor is \$1/j\omega{}C\$ which is a negative imaginary number because \$1/j = -j\$.

So if you wrote the transfer function in terms of reactance, you'd have

$$\tilde{v}_o = \frac{R}{R+jX_C}\tilde{v}_i$$

because \$X_C\$ is generally taken as \$-1/\omega{}C\$.

Comment: Wow, yeah. That's why, stupid question. Thanks for the help!